# Proving that $\{\to, \lnot\}$ is logically complete

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Prove that $\{\to,\lnot\}$ is logically complete.

It is known that $\{\land, \lor, \lnot\}$ is logically complete.

Comment: Hint: Can you compose $\rightarrow$ and $\neg$ together to make something equivalent to $\vee$ and $\wedge$?

Comment: [To use curly braces in mathematical notation, please use `\{` and `\}` inside the dollar signs.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11169/856)

Comment: @Discrete: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? There is little more to solving this problem than actually trying things -- so it's very difficult to give useful advice if you don't offer more.

Comment: @Benjamin: You're probably thinking nor. (it's more common, for some reason, to use nand, though)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It suffices to show that we can express $\land$ and $\lor$ in terms of $\neg$ and $\to$. I'll do the first one. Notice that:
\begin{align*}
p \land q &\equiv \neg\neg p \land \neg\neg q \\
&\equiv \neg(\neg (p) \lor (\neg q)) \\
&\equiv \neg(p \to \neg q) \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do this.  I'll use a way a probably lesser known way.

Suppose p true and (p→q) true.  Consequently, by the rule of detachment (or "modus ponens"), it follows that q is true.  Thus, under these conditions, either p is true or q is true.  That is,

"{p, (p→q)} $\vdash$ q" entails that (p∨q) holds true.

Now let's move the turnstile $\vdash$ just once to the left.  We get:

p $\vdash$ [(p→q)→q].  We moved from q as true to (p∨q) as true above.  If p is true, it also works out that (p∨q) holds true.  Thus,

"p $\vdash$ [(p→q)→q]" entails that (p∨q) holds true.

Now, p implies [(p→q)→q].  Now consider the following "if p holds true, then if q also holds true, then p holds true."  But, we can also say "if p holds true, then if (p∨q) holds true, then p holds true."  We can also say, "if q holds true, then if (p→q) holds true, then q holds true also."  So, p implies [(p→q)→q] holds true, and q implies that [(p→q)→q] holds true.  Since the truth table for conjunction is "less than" the truth table for disjunction, if p holds true or q holds true, then [(p→q)→q] holds true.  So, in symbols we can tell that

```
 1. {(p∨q)→[(p→q)→q]} holds true.
```

Now suppose that [(p→q)→q] holds true.  We know that that [p→(p∨q)] from the above in some sense at least.  Suppose p is not true.  Consequently, $\lnot$p is true.  Since [$\lnot$p→(p→q)] always holds true for all p and q, we have that (p→q) holds true.  By the hypothesis, we can detach that q also holds true.  q implies that (p∨q) holds true.  Thus, under the hypothesis, [$\lnot$p→(p∨q)], and [p→(p∨q)].  Since (p∨$\lnot$p) holds true, we can thus infer that (p∨q) holds true.  Discharging the hypothesis we have that

```
 2. {[(p→q)→q]→(p∨q)}.
```

So, from 1. and 2. we can infer [(p→q)→q] and (p∨q) logically equivalent and that's what we wanted to get to here.  Of course, you can do a truth table to check this also.

For "∧" do you know the De Morgan laws?