# Showing $\lor$ in terms of $\to$ and $\lnot$

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I was looking at a question a user posted yesterday (link below). And one of the answers mentioned one could express $∨$ in terms of  $\to$ and $\lnot$. 
In terms of $\land$ he stated it can be expressed like such:

\begin{align*}
p \land q &\equiv \neg\neg p \land \neg\neg q \\
&\equiv \neg(\neg (p) \lor (\neg q)) \\
&\equiv \neg(p \to \neg q) \\
\end{align*}

I've been thinking about how something like that could be done for a while now and its starting to bug me. Out of curiosity was that the right procedure and if so how could it be shown for $\lor$.

link: [Proving that $\{\to, \lnot\}$ is logically complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518536/proving-that-to-lnot-is-logically-complete)

Comment: This deduction is correct. Showing that it is true requires a set of rules of inference or a truth-table. What method are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p\lor q=\lnot(\lnot p\land\lnot q)=\dots$

Comment: Wait so what your saying is that the end result is the same for both **and** and **or**. Because what I assume follows from that step is what is shown in the original post.

Comment: $\dots = \lnot(\lnot ((\lnot p)\to\lnot (\lnot q)))=(\lnot p)\to q$

Comment: Oops did not notice that there was **and** inside the () and not an **or**. That makes sense. Thank you.